# How do I lock div so it won't move when I scroll

Tags: html, css

I've been having a problem, and I can't find a solution. I have a div with 3 lines of text

```
<div class="Text">
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <h2>I'm John Doe</h2>
    <h3>Param para param</h3>
</div>
```

plus I added `div` so I can scroll

```
<div id="1" style="min-height:1000px;"></div>
<div id="2" style="min-height:1000px;" ></div>
```

Please tell me how to lock the div with the text so it won't move when I scroll

> PS: position:fixed - doesn't work

Comment: use `position:fixed`

Comment: Yeah I tried that , still moving when I scroll

Comment: can you try with the below snippet

Comment: You need to post the markup with the CSS you are using that doesn't work. What you show isn't helpful and doesn't show the problem, as required, and may get your question closed.

Answer (score 2):

I have used `position:fixed` property , div doesn't move when we scroll, try with snippet

```css
.text {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text" >
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <h2>I'm John Doe</h2>
    <h3>Param para param</h3>
</div>

<div id="1" style="min-height:1000px;width:100%; background:#f1f1f1;"></div>
<div id="2" style="min-height:1000px;width:100%; background:#ddd;" ></div>
```

Comment: Still moving when I scroll, I know it should work , but it doesn't

Comment: can you post your code ? and recheck the snippet i have added background

Comment: When you say it "moves" when you scroll, you mean it's not in the same place on the screen ? Or do you mean it moves along with the scrolling (thus staying at the same place on the screen) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can give `position:fixed` to the particular `div`

```
.text {
    positon: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```